# Time series graph using node and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

How do I create a time series graph  using node js and angular js . Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us what code you already have related to your question? And maybe some of the things you tried but did not work? This question (to me) just sounds like you were too lazy to use google.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply i used google and i made a graph. My requirement is to make a graph which contains only time series.

Comment: Neither node nor angular handle graphics, ones a server language and the other is a client framework. That said I would consider looking at a client library for graphics - I strongly recommend D3.js. Then angular and node can handle the client-server communications and the rendering is left to a graphics library.

Comment: @Joe Chart.js is also a very nice one, and very easy to use (in my opinion easier than d3). Might be useful for OP to compare the 2 and choose whatever is best for him

Comment: Thanks FullyHumanProgrammer chart.js is really good  and very easy to use . I chnaged my code from highcharts to chart.js.

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer you are absolutely right, Chart,js is much more ready to plug into this problem.

Comment: Hey FullyHumanProgrammer can you tell me how i pass JSON array object as data in chart js.